# $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{\sin 2 x}{2(2+\sin 2 x)}+\frac{\sin 3 x}{3(3+\sin 3 x)}+\ldots+\frac{\sin n x}{n(n+\sin n x)}\right)$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I tried to write $\frac{\sin n x}{n(n+\sin n x)} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + \sin n x}$. After that, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

$$\left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+\sin n x}\right| \leq \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I can use the Cauchy criterion for series.